# indexOf and if statement?

Tags: javascript

```
var lang = ['en', 'es'];
if(lang.indexOf('en') < 0){
    console.log('fail');
}
```

I'm trying to check if 'en' is in the lang array. The above code always spits out a fail. Why?

Comment: It doesn't fail on the latest version of Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of what i'm doing. Is there anything different in the process I'm going through here from yours and can you perhaps turn your post into a snippet so we can see for ourselves what is happening? https://jsfiddle.net/v4L27ua0/

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just check if it is undefined?

```
var lang = ['en', 'es'];
if(typeof lang['en'] !== undefined){
    console.log('fail');
}
```

Comment: @Marvin Medeiros If you want to check against `undefined`, you need `typeof`. If you don't use `typeof`, you need to check against the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: Scott just fixed, try it now @panthro

Comment: Arrays don't have a property `en`.